# Angular UI Typeahead can't set options (like footer template)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, typeahead

I'd like to add a custom footer to the results where I can wire up some paging. I see that I can specify a footer template in the options, but can't find any examples of how to set those options from a controller.

The footer template would display "Now showing 1-{{offsetEnd}} of {{result.count}} Load More

Thank you everyone!

This is the tag I'm using:

```js
 < input type = "text"
 id = "search"
 name = "search"
 ng - model = "profile.selectedProfile"
 typeahead = "o.itemvalue as o.itemtext for o in getProfiles($viewValue) | filter: $viewValue"
 typeahead - input - formatter = "formatLabel($model)"
 class = "form-control"
 autocomplete = "off" / >
```

**UPDATE**
I converted this to a directive, and incorporated a footer that displays the total record count.

```js
function findProfile() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="text" id="search" name="search" ng-model="selectedProfile" typeahead="o as o.itemtext for o in getProfiles($viewValue) | filter: $viewValue" typeahead-input-formatter="formatLabel($model)" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />',
    controller: function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.itemCount = 0;
      $scope.getProfiles = function(searchtext) {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:61402/api/Profile/FindProfile?searchText=' + searchtext)
          .then(function(response) {
            $scope.itemCount = response.data.itemcount;
            return response.data.items;
          });
      }

      $scope.formatLabel = function(model) {
        return model == undefined ? '' : model.itemtext;
      }

    }
  };
}
```

And the template:

```js
angular.run(['$templateCache',
  function($templateCache) {
    var template = '' +
      '<ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-show="isOpen()" ng-style="{top: position.top+\'px\', left: position.left+\'px\'}" style="display: block;" role="listbox" aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}">' +
      '<li ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)" role="option" id="{{match.id}}">' +
      '<div typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" template-url="templateUrl"></div>' +
      '</li>' +
      '<li>Records Returned: {{$parent.itemCount}}</li>' +
      '</ul>';

    $templateCache.put('template/typeahead/typeahead-popup.html', template);
  }
])
```

Comment: Do you want add a footer to typeahead's results? Can you add some example code?

Comment: Yes, into typeahead's results. This is the tag I'm using: <input type="text" id="search" name="search" ng-model="profile.selectedProfile" typeahead="o.itemvalue as o.itemtext for o in getProfiles($viewValue) | filter: $viewValue" typeahead-input-formatter="formatLabel($model)" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I had to perform a bit of a hack here, but I liked your question.

What I ended up working with was the `typeahead-template-url`. Unfortunately, the documentation for it is very hard to find, yet I had done a lot of work with this in the past. For some of the documentation, [**try here**](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead). Even more unfortunate, I never documented where I found the default `typeahead-template-url` either, and I couldn't find it online today. Luckily, I did have my version of it on file.

Here is what I had before hacking at it:

```
<a>
    <span bind-html-unsafe="match.model.label | myModelLabelFilter"></span>
</a>
```

As you can guess, this is the `template` for each match shown in the `Angular Typeahead`, and placing a `filter` here (`myModelLabelFilter` in our example) is a great way to modify and inject mostly whatever you want into each shown match.

Now, this may not have been the best way to add **one** button to the bottom of the `typeahead` popup, but it's the only thing that I could think of. So, we will need to only show a button after the last `match`. How about `ng-if`.

```
<a>
    <span bind-html-unsafe="match.model.label | cmcTicketingTypeaheadFilter"></span>
</a>
<div    
    ng-if="($parent.$parent.matches.length - 1) === index" 
    style="border-top:1px solid #DDDDDD;" 
>
    Example 
    <button 
        ng-click="$emit('foo', this)" 
        class="bt btn-primary" 
    >
        Click To Emit
    </button>
</div>
```

*...purposely formatted weird to avoid scroll-bars...*

..and this is what I got:

[image: Typeahead Template Footer]

***You may be wondering...*** what the `$parent.$parent.matches` thing is all about.

First of all, we are working in the `scope` of the `Typeahead Directive`. 
In this `scope` we have three values: `match`, `index`, and `query`. I needed to move up the `scope` levels until we reached a `parent scope` that had a listing of all returned `matches`. Every `scope` has the `$parent` attribute, showing its `parent scope`.

**NOW, for your full answer!** I am not sure how you plan to access your `scope` for your `offsetEnd` variables, but I would suggest making it accessible on your matches.

Instead of passing an `array of strings`, you can pass an array of objects. This is why my template shows `match.model.label`. I used an array of objects where each object was:

```
{
    label: 'Alabama'
    value: 0
}
```

This way I can grab any value I want from a user selection, not just the label. I would suggest placing a value on these options here somewhere and using `ng-if` to help you do the `matches` paging like you are talking about.

Good Luck! Hope that helped! And dang, as I was typing this up someone posted another answer!

Comment: The last piece of this will be to add a link in the footer that will pull another x records and update the results and filters. Looking at events now...

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the **typeahead** template.

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .run(['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
    
    var template = '' +
      '<ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-show="isOpen()" ng-style="{top: position.top+\'px\', left: position.left+\'px\'}" style="display: block;" role="listbox" aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}">' +
        '<li ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)" role="option" id="{{match.id}}">' +
          '<div typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" template-url="templateUrl"></div>' +
        '</li>' +
        '<li>The footer</li>' +
      '</ul>';
    
    $templateCache.put('template/typeahead/typeahead-popup.html', template);
  }])
  
  .controller('mainController', function($scope) {

    $scope.selected = undefined;
    $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas'];
});
```

In this example, I copied the template of [github-typeahead-template](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/0.12.1/template/typeahead/typeahead-popup.html), the added a extra `li` (the footer) element inside of the `ul` element and, finally, I put the template in the angular's cache.

You can get a full example in [custom angular-ui bootstrap](http://plnkr.co/edit/OcpDgX?p=preview) and the template name https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/0.12.1/src/typeahead/typeahead.js#L452

This technique works with **ui-bootstrap-tpls.js** (include the templates) and the **ui-bootstrap.js** (without templates) but it is better to have the template in a file (typeahead-with-footer.html) than in a string. You have several options: use grunt, a script tag or create the static file (typeahead-with-footer.html) in you server (only works in with **ui-bootstrap.js**).

Comment: This was extremely helpful and the format I ended up using. I marked @WebWanderer as the answer because he provided a way to access the scope. I'll post my solution shortly. Thank you @Pollin!